# Azure Data Factory Copy XML Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm copying XML to a database using a "Copy Activity".

XML file has a nested structure so I have defined a "Collection reference" at "Cond_Tbl_Data_Record" level.
[mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9xVR.png)
the following is written to db correctly.

```
`<Cond_Tbl_Data_Set>
    <Cond_Tbl_Data_Record>
        <Base_Per_Quantity>1</Base_Per_Quantity>
        <Base_UOM_Code>GA</Base_UOM_Code>
        <Condition_Table_ID>A02</Condition_Table_ID>
        <Condition_Type>COCO</Condition_Type>
        <Condition_Value>829</Condition_Value>
        <Currency_Code>USC</Currency_Code>
        <Extraction_Time>20230113 19:41:03</Extraction_Time>
        <Key_Values>US/000001/001</Key_Values>
        <Valid_From_Date>20230113</Valid_From_Date>
        <Valid_To_Date>99991231</Valid_To_Date>
        <Effective_Start_Time>13:22:42</Effective_Start_Time>
        <Condition_Change_Value>300</Condition_Change_Value>
    </Cond_Tbl_Data_Record>
    <Cond_Tbl_Data_Record>
        <Base_Per_Quantity>1</Base_Per_Quantity>
        <Base_UOM_Code>GA</Base_UOM_Code>
        <Condition_Table_ID>A04</Condition_Table_ID>
        <Condition_Type>COCO</Condition_Type>
        <Condition_Value>829</Condition_Value>
        <Currency_Code>USC</Currency_Code>
        <Extraction_Time>20230113 19:41:03</Extraction_Time>
        <Key_Values>US/000001/002</Key_Values>
        <Valid_From_Date>20230113</Valid_From_Date>
        <Valid_To_Date>99991231</Valid_To_Date>
        <Effective_Start_Time>13:22:42</Effective_Start_Time>
        <Condition_Change_Value>300</Condition_Change_Value>
    </Cond_Tbl_Data_Record>
</Cond_Tbl_Data_Set>`
```

but the following is not written to db at all.

```
`<Cond_Tbl_Data_Set>
    <Cond_Tbl_Data_Record>
        <Base_Per_Quantity>1</Base_Per_Quantity>
        <Base_UOM_Code>GA</Base_UOM_Code>
        <Condition_Table_ID>A02</Condition_Table_ID>
        <Condition_Type>COCO</Condition_Type>
        <Condition_Value>829</Condition_Value>
        <Currency_Code>USC</Currency_Code>
        <Extraction_Time>20230113 19:41:03</Extraction_Time>
        <Key_Values>US/000001/001</Key_Values>
        <Valid_From_Date>20230113</Valid_From_Date>
        <Valid_To_Date>99991231</Valid_To_Date>
        <Effective_Start_Time>13:22:42</Effective_Start_Time>
        <Condition_Change_Value>300</Condition_Change_Value>
    </Cond_Tbl_Data_Record>
</Cond_Tbl_Data_Set>`
```

I tried to reimport schema but still did not work

Comment: Here is output from the copy activity. "dataRead": 1385,
 "dataWritten": 536,
 "filesRead": 1,
 "sourcePeakConnections": 1,
 "sinkPeakConnections": 2,
 "rowsRead": 1,
 "rowsCopied": 2,
 "copyDuration": 11,
 "throughput": 0.277,
 "errors": [],

Comment: what is you are sink where you are copying this data?

Comment: I am writing to sq db

Answer (score 0):

> As per information you are providing when your file has single object in array Its not getting copied.

**The cause of issue is when you have single object in array it will take it as object not as array.**

To resolve the issue, you have to first clear the mapping and then again import the mapping. So, it will take that as another object not an array as shown in below image:

[image]

**My sample input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I sometimes get files with one record and sometimes with multiple records. If I clear and import schema it will only work for one record files and will stop working for multiple records. I need it to work for both.

Comment: try without importing schema. it will automatically detect it and map it accordingly